# How do I echo a PHP variable into a href attribute for a stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, directory, href

I have these three files:

**index.php**

```
<?php include('variables.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TestWebsite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo($folder . 'css/styles.css')?>">
</head>
```

**variables.php**

```
<?php
$folder = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Website/";
```

**css/styles.css**

```
/* Insert styling stuff here */
```

index.php and variables.php are stored on the root directory. For some reason the stylesheet refuses to link, and I need help with figuring out why. This works fine though:
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

- Tried putting `<?php echo($folder . 'css/styles.css')?>` into a separate php file to see if I appended the directory correctly.
- Tried moving styles.css out of its parent folder into the main directory
- Tried     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $folder ?>css/styles.css">`
- In index.php there are include()s that use $folder and work just fine.
- Am starting to wonder if its a scope issue

Comment: Just use the relative path, not the whole. Look at functions like basename(). https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename

Comment: File paths for anything inside an HTML file (css, js, images, URLs) need to have the domain (starts with http or a double slash `//`) or be relative to the domain (starts with a single slash). They should not start with `C:`. If you look at the source in the browser, your variables are probably echoing just fine, but the path is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have a protocol specified for the local file path. In that case, it is the protocol path `file://`.

Instead of an absolute URL, it is more appropriate to enter a relative URL and view your test pages via a "simple web server" (e.g. [Built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)).

Comment: Please do not recommend using `file:///`. That will break the page once they upload it to a live server

Comment: I reacted only narrowly to his problem.

Of course, it is better to avoid it - for the programmer.But as information, he should know. Today, a web browser can be like a PDF file or image browser, and there the file:// appears in the URL.